# Замена системных звуков в Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Хотел изменить звук подключения и удаления флешки на Ubuntu 20.04. В сети нашел информацию, что можно просто заменить файлы с соответствующими именами на свои с тем же именем и расширением. Сделал, звуки пропали совсем.

Поменял два файлика в usr/share/sounds в двух подпапках
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно вылечить?

Comment: расширение расширением, а формат файла этому расширению соотвествует? или просто мп3 переименовал?

Comment: Конвертировал в Аудио Ogg FLAC (audio/x-flac+ogg), оригинальные файлы были Аудио Ogg Vorbis (audio/x-vorbis+ogg). Это может быть причиной?

Comment: я бы попробовал для теста взять другой ога файл из этой же папки и дать ему нужное имя, чтобы был наверняка подходящий. Будет работать на событие или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно внимательно конвертировать файлы:
Выбирать строго формат и кодек: OGA кодек Vorbis. Другие кодеки и форматы система не воспринимает